# After building julia from source, what's safe to delete?

Tags: makefile, julia

I was able to build it on a tiny computer, but the result now takes up ~ 1 GB of the 1.3 GB I had free.  Most of this is in the /deps folder -- this is safe to delete after the build, correct?

Comment: Are there dynamic libraries in there... That is the only thing I can think would be needed... If it is a normal configure make unixy thing the. After make install you can get rid of the whole source dir in theory

Comment: My patience is ... lacking. it appears to still be working without /deps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The */deps* folder is not needed, that is correct but the simple thing to do is `make install` and that will create a directory julia-**some hex number**.  That directory is all that is needed and it can be copied anywhere and everything else deleted afterwards, but the */deps* folder will probably need to exist for that to happen to satisfy make.

On my system a recent build takes up 148 MB `May 19 19:36 julia-eb5da264e8`

```
du -sm julia-eb5da264e8
148 julia-eb5da264e8
```

I have not attempted to run julia out of a *non-installed* directory structure.

There are some secondary things that occur that may or may not be needed like making julia-debug and documentation, but then there also may be secondary link patching too and that is important, ill leave the recent [output of make install in a gist](https://gist.github.com/waTeim/0e4c5067f0d516252a04). You can attempt to simply make install yourself and see if that works, but you may find with the deps folder gone now, any make will begin by trying to regenerate it or not work at all.

If it doesn't, you might be able to reproduce the make install steps by hand from the gist, but I would suggest just starting over; let the build happen again.  There's enough room for make install.  Keep the generated directory and delete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

After you "make install" It should be safe to delete the whole build folder.

Also packages added by Pkg.add is installed under ~/.julia you should need nothing from the compilation folder.